# How to edit values, such as MouseState in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

I was wondering if there is a way to change the state or value of the `MouseState` whilst debugging, as I want to make the left button `Pressed` on the mouse but if I try to type anything like that in, I receive an error.

Any ideas, people?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MouseState` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.mousestate.aspx):

```
public MouseState (
         int x,
         int y,
         int scrollWheel,
         ButtonState leftButton,
         ButtonState middleButton,
         ButtonState rightButton,
         ButtonState xButton1,
         ButtonState xButton2
)
```

As MSDN says:

> Games normally use GetState to get the true mouse state. This
>   constructor is used instead to simulate mouse input for passing within
>   the game's own input subsystem.

But I don't think that you can do something like this while debugging.